# What is $\binom{n}{-k}$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

> What is $\binom{n}{-k}$ ? If $n,k\ge0$

In Wikipedia there's a case where $n$ is negative and not $k$

But if Pascal's rule still holds, I get for example for $k=0$;

$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{1}$

$1=\binom{n-1}{-1}+1\implies\binom{n}{-1}=0$ for any $n$

Is that true, there must be a generalization of the formula, can you help please.

Comment: The German language Wikipedia [article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomialkoeffizient#Verallgemeinerung) lists a definition using Betafunctions. Your case is noted as having zero value for positive integer $k$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Two_real_or_complex_valued_arguments

Comment: @mvw Awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Many (all, maybe?) results about binomial coefficients hold if you define:

$$\displaystyle \binom n k = 0 \text{ for } k < 0$$